# how to identify same class in android?

Tags: java, android

I see the classloader load class in android and I have a question. how to identify the same class in this process. I google classloader principle and find some person say:

if a class have same classname and have same classloader, that is a same class. But I use android studio and I define a class named **View** and I use it in other class, I find have two class in hint. one is my define, another is the  system class.

But base on Parents Mode in **classloader**, there have the system class in right way, how to understand it ?

I am very doubt！

Comment: Is that a java question or Android-Studio?

Comment: During compile time only the package and class name count. The class loader comes into play during runtime.

Comment: @agilob that is a java question maybe , I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I use android [...] and I define a class named "View" and I use it in other class, I find have two class in hint. One is [mine], another is the system class.

If I understand correctly, the classloader is doing it's job correctly and loads both `com.your.package.View` and `android.view.View`. You pick which one can simply be referenced by `View` using an `import` statement, otherwise you need to fully qualify the name, such as the two classes I just described.

Same in pure Java, if you were to write a `String` class overlapping `java.lang.String`

Comment: if have same name class in com.your.package and how to deal with ? see which one load earlier？

Comment: You shouldn't be able to make two classes of the same name in the same package. You will see a compilation error.

Comment: The general solution to the problem is to make your class names self-describing and not overlap with system classes, if you can.